# Build Error in IOS connected with visual studio community 2013

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2012, ssl

I followed the steps for building a iphone app http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-Tools-for-Apache-Cordova/Building-Apache-Cordova-Apps-with-Visual-Studio
The first command in terminal was succesfully install the npm ,but when I try the second command(vs-mda-remote generateClientCert), I got response as

iMac-KQ:~ test$ vs-mda-remote generateClientCert vs-mda-remote Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 0.2.5 One or both of required CA files /Users/test/remote-builds/certs/ca-key.pem and /Users/test/remote-builds/certs/ca-cert.pem not found.

What should I do? I am trying to download certificates for Ca-cert, But I cant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it, I dont ve write permission in that Imac system, That is why it cant able create those files("files /Users/test/remote-builds/certs/ca-key.pem and /Users/test/remote-builds/certs/ca-cert.pem"). I set write permission to reponsed folder, My problem gone. I got sample IOS application.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error , Actually showhidden all files can also solve the problem .